# ffmpeg- drawtext above specified coordinates

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible to draw a text above the specified coordinates? Example i want to write "Hello" at coordinate (100,100). By default ffmpeg draws the text in top to bottom manner, i.e , Starting point would be 100,100 and will draw downwards.
Can it be drawn in a bottom up manner? (Start upwards from 100,100).
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the rendered text width and height variables

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf drawtext=x=100-tw:y=100-th out.mp4
```

Here, (100,100), measured from the top-left, will be the lower-right corner of the drawn text.

---

To just keep it bottom-aligned but from L-to-R

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf drawtext=x=100:y=100-th out.mp4
```

Comment: Hi. In this case, the text ends on the lower right corner. Can it start from left to right? Start from (100,100) and end towards left. Just that (100,100) should be the base, not top.

Comment: Hi. How can we achieve the same with overlay filter?

Comment: Bottom-aligned L-to-R:  `overlay=x=100:y=100-h`